# GMail API/Google Workspace Add-on to automatically process emails with my own API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-gsuite

I'm wondering if I can use the GMail API, or some Google Workspace Add-On to aautomatically handle emails received by a specific address.

I have my own  web app API, and I'd like any email sent to a specific address to trigger an API call to my web app, without a user having to manually do anything. (I can only seem to find references to how to do this using a visual interface that a user must interact with)

Ideally, this would work for a group address, but an actual account works too if that's a limitation.

Cheers!

Comment: Its possible, but if you want to make the add-on publicly accessible via Google Workspace Marketplace, then your app will need to undergo a security assessment which will run you anywhere from US$15K to US$75K (implementation requires the use of restricted scopes). If you don't plan to publish the add-on or if you have the option of publishing it under a private Google Domain you won't incur that cost. Check out the [Gmail API Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) guide for implementation details.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot - Thanks for the info. I had misunderstood the push notifications use case, that should be perfect. This is all internal stuff, so no cost in this case